# Use jquery / ajax to run small php script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to give a div a random background image. I have a very simple bit of php in the head of my page.

```
<?php 
$bg = rand(1, 6); 
$bgchange = $bg.".jpg"; 
?>
```

followed by

```
<style type="text/css">
.cover {
background-image: url('../img/backgrounds/<?php echo $bgchange; ?>');
}
</style>
```

This is working but sometimes fails for some reason especially on a poor internet connection.

What I want to do is use jquery so that on document ready AJAX points to the php file (the php i currently have in the header), I am hoping this will make the php more reliable as it is not trying to load the image until after the document is ready.

I've been told 
You can detect the "document-ready" event with a Javascript script and when that is triggered, perform an AJAX request to a PHP page that will run the script you need.

With jQuery it gets as simple as using ready() and ajax().

Can anyone suggest how to implement this as I cant find anyone who has already done this anywhere...

The solution i used is:

```
var images = [
'1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg', '5.jpg'];

var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
var randomImage = "images/" + randomNumber + ".jpg";
jQuery.ajax(randomImage);

$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
$('.cover').css({ 'background-image': 'url(' + randomImage + ')' }).addClass('loaded');
})
```

and the CSS

```
body, html {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.cover {
height: 100%; width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
background: #bada55;
background-position: 50% 50%;
transition: opacity 2s ease;
opacity: 0;
}

.loaded {
opacity: 1;
}
```

only one of the background images is downloaded and then to be able to perform a function such as a subtle fade in only when that image has loaded etc.

Comment: no need to make a call to server to get a random number between 1 and 6. Do it with javascript. Random image posts come up all the time...not hard to find in a web search

Comment: Yeah, You would be surprised on how little info there is to do this properly, so that only one of the background images is downloaded and then to be able to perform a function such as a subtle fade in only when that image has loaded etc.

Comment: how big images are we talking here? What do you mean loading fails on poor internet?

Comment: As already mentioned above in the comments, you can do this with JS / jQuery pretty easily: http://jsfiddle.net/gkbSU/